# Load pictures from resources, into an array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have some photos in my resources. How can I access these files and load them into an array? Any help would be much appreciated! This is for iOS.

Thanks!

~Carpetfizz

Comment: iOS or OSX? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @rmaddy iOS. Haven't tried anything because I don't know how to access those files.

Comment: `[UIImage imageNamed:]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the UIImage method called `imageNamed:`.

Use it like this:

```
NSArray *images = @[
  [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1"],
  [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2"],
  [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3"]
];
```

A more general way to get access to files in your app’s “Resources” folder is with `NSBundle`:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSURL *imageURL = [bundle URLForResource:@"image" withExtension:@"png"];
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to loop through the names? For example imageNamedWith: @"x", etc.

Comment: See my edit. You can get a list of resources with `NSBundle -URLsForResourcesWithExtension:subdirectory:` then loop through to find the files you want. If you’re trying to get a bunch of frames for an animation it might easiest to construct the names and load the images in a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this. Say, names of your images are image1.png , image2.png , image3.png . Then ,

```
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"];

NSArray *ImageArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:image1,image2,image3, nil];
```

Your images are loaded into Array. Now you can use them like this , say you load one in your UIImageView called myImageView.

```
myImageView.image = [ImageArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

or

```
myImageView.image = image1 ;
```

Hope it helps.